# Syncing parse data with coredata, how do I figure out which objects to delete?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, parse-platform

I have successfully written the code to download the parse objects, fetch the current objects in my database and then compare.

My algorithm:

I iterate through the parse objects and run a fetchrequest and compare their objectID's. If I get nothing, I make a new object for my database. Otherwise I then look at the modifiedDate I have in my database and the updatedAt from parse and compare to see if I need to set new values. This code works great.

The code:

```
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
    if error == nil {
        if let objects = objects {
            for object in objects {
                let object = object as! PFObject
                let name = object["name"] as! String
                let email = object["email"] as! String
                let subjectsTaught = object["subjectsTaught"] as [String: String]
                let category = object["category"] as! String
                let uniqueID = object.objectId!
                let modifiedDate = object.updatedAt!
                let fetchRequest2 = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Teacher")
                fetchRequest2.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "uniqueID == %@", uniqueID)
                var error2: NSError?
                if let foundTeachers = self.managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest2, error: &error2) as? [Teacher] {
                    if foundTeachers.isEmpty == true {
                        let teacher = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Teacher", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext) as! Teacher
                        teacher.name = name
                        teacher.email = email
                        teacher.subjectsTaught = subjectsTaught
                        teacher.category = category
                        teacher.uniqueID = uniqueID
                        teacher.modifiedDate = modifiedDate
                    } else {
                        if let teacher = foundTeachers.first {
                            let date1 = teacher.modifiedDate
                            let date2 = modifiedDate
                            let compareResult = date1.compare(date2)
                            if compareResult == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending {
                                teacher.setValue(name, forKey: "name")
                                teacher.setValue(email, forKey: "email")
                                teacher.setValue(subjectsTaught, forKey: "subjectsTaught")
                                teacher.setValue(category, forKey: "category")
                                teacher.setValue(modifiedDate, forKey: "modifiedDate")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                var error: NSError?
                if !self.managedObjectContext.save(&error) {
                    println("Error \(error)")
                    abort()
                }
            }
        }
```

My question is how should I figure out which objects where not in parse? I don't want to query parse for every object in my database as I assume that would be network intensive.

Should I do a fetchrequest for all Teacher objects in the beginning and as I iterate through the parse objects, delete them as I go? If I have objects left, those should be deleted?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured out what to do. I ended up running a fetchrequest first for all teacher and appending their names to an array. During the parse iteration, I deleted teachers from that list as I went through them and at the end, used that list to delete teachers from the database.

```
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
        fetchRequest.entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Teacher", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext)
        var error: NSError?
        var foundTeacherNames = [String]()
        if let foundTeachers = self.managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error) as? [Teacher] {
            for teacher in foundTeachers {
                foundTeacherNames.append(teacher.name)
            }
        }
        //Find teachers in parse database
        let query = PFQuery(className: "TeacherList")
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                if let objects = objects {
                    for object in objects {
                        let object = object as! PFObject
                        let name = object["name"] as! String
                        let email = object["email"] as! String
                        let subjectsTaught = object["subjectsTaught"] as! [String: String]
                        let category = object["category"] as! String
                        let uniqueID = object.objectId!
                        let modifiedDate = object.updatedAt!
                        let fetchRequest2 = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Teacher")
                        fetchRequest2.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "uniqueID == %@", uniqueID)
                        var error2: NSError?
                        if let foundTeachers = self.managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest2, error: &error2) as? [Teacher] {
                            if foundTeachers.isEmpty == true {
                                let teacher = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Teacher", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext) as! Teacher
                                teacher.name = name
                                teacher.email = email
                                teacher.subjectsTaught = subjectsTaught
                                teacher.category = category
                                teacher.uniqueID = uniqueID
                                teacher.modifiedDate = modifiedDate
                            } else {
                                if let teacher = foundTeachers.first {
                                    let date1 = teacher.modifiedDate
                                    let date2 = modifiedDate
                                    let compareResult = date1.compare(date2)
                                    if compareResult == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending {
                                        teacher.setValue(name, forKey: "name")
                                        teacher.setValue(email, forKey: "email")
                                        teacher.setValue(subjectsTaught, forKey: "subjectsTaught")
                                        teacher.setValue(category, forKey: "category")
                                        teacher.setValue(modifiedDate, forKey: "modifiedDate")
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            if contains(foundTeacherNames, name) {
                                let i = find(foundTeacherNames, name)!
                                foundTeacherNames.removeAtIndex(i)
                            }
                        }
                        var error: NSError?
                        if !self.managedObjectContext.save(&error) {
                            println("Error \(error)")
                            abort()
                        }
                        if !foundTeacherNames.isEmpty {
                            for teacher in foundTeacherNames {
                                let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Teacher")
                                request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name = %@", teacher)
                                if let fetchResults = self.managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil) as? [NSManagedObject] {
                                    if fetchResults.count != 0 {
                                        self.managedObjectContext.deleteObject(fetchResults[0])
                                    }
                                }

                            }
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the best way is to fetch all entities and then check for the unique ids. You could use key-value-coding (or its Swift equivalents such as `map`) to just get the ids you are interested in.

```
let existingIDs = entitiesFromParse.map() { $0.uniqueID as? String }
```

You can then check if an ID exists with

```
let idExists = existingIDs.contains(idToCheck)
```

This is preferable to multiple fetch requests which are expensive.

Comment: just be careful that you are indeed retrieving all objects for your class, i.e returnedObjects.count < query limit

Comment: could you please elaborate and maybe give an example of how you are doing this @Mundi

Comment: @Tom I think the explanation is pretty complete. You will have to write the code yourself ;-).